# SQL Server subquery not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE Year(dateColumn) = 2015;
```

This is working for me as long as the `dateColumn` is in table1. However, I have that column in master_table. So I am trying:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE Year(SELECT dateColumnName FROM master_table mt WHERE mt.table_id = table1.id) = 2015;
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE Year(dateColumnName FROM master_table mt WHERE mt.table_id = table1.id) = 2015;
```

My master_table is a list of tables, and the `dateColumnName` field has literal string value `dateColumn` which I'll use in table1. The reason is I have to go thru this is that some tables have the column name `dateColumn` and some has `date_column`, all stored in master_table.

Summary: I want the second `SELECT` statement to return either `dateColumn` or `date_column` depending on the value in the master table and depending on the WHERE condition, and use it for my first `SELECT` statement.

Sample Data:

table1

`id` `Name` `Email`  `dateColumn`

`1` `John` `abc@xyz.co` `2013-01-15`

table2

`id` `Name` `Email`  `date_column`

`2` `Paul` `def@xyz.co` `2014-03-05`

master_table

`table_id` `dateColumnName`

`1` `dateColumn`

`2` `date_column`

I need to filter the data from table1 and table2 based on the date, and for that I need the column name. Those column names are stored in the master_table, so I match their id's by matching with the table_id's stored in master_table, and retrieve the column name using a second `SELECT` statement

Comment: Add sample table data (both tables), and the expected result.

Comment: How master_table and table1 relate to each other? What is key between them? How do you know which rows from table1 belong master_table rows?

Comment: How do I add sample table data? @jarlh

Comment: Press Edit. Type data in pretty columns, mark it and click `{}`. Save Edits.

Comment: alternative is to create a **sqlFiddle**

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a subquery, you have an argument that starts with `select`.  The parentheses are for the function, not the subquery.

The syntax for a subquery would have extra parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE Year( (SELECT dateColumnName FROM master_table mt WHERE condition) ) = 2015;
```

The more natural way to write this would use `exists` or simple equality:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE 2015 = (SELECT YEAR(dateColumnName) FROM master_table mt WHERE condition);
```

Note that this does not require extra parentheses, because there is no function.

Comment: Note that this will either result in ALL ROWS from table1, or NO ROWS from table1, depending in datecolumnname is 2015, because as far as I can see, your filter has nothing to do with table1, so will either result in true (2015=2015), or false (2015=SomeOtherYear), for every row of table1.

Comment: There are data from more than one year, and I can change the filter from 2015 to 2014 or some other year, so it doesn't necessarily have to return all or no rows. @Gordon Linoff the double parentheses isn't working either

Comment: @BivoKasaju . . . The second method is really the right way to go, although `IN` is more appropriate than `=`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In second method you have simply used `Year(dateColumnName)` when that column contains `dateColumn` or `date_column)` and not the real date. I need the second SELECT statement INSIDE the Year parantheses so that it returns the column name from master table that contains date in other tables. Refer to my first and second code and my sample date in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want here is a single JOIN query:

```
select id, datefld, email from
(
select
  mt.table_id as id,
    case mt.dateColumnName
        when 'dateColumn' then t1.`name`
        when 'date_column' then t2.`name`
    end as name, 
    case mt.dateColumnName
        when 'dateColumn' then t1.dateColumn
        when 'date_column' then t2.date_column
    end as datefld,
    case mt.dateColumnName
        when 'dateColumn' then t1.email
        when 'date_column' then t2.email
    end as email 
from
  master_table mt
left join
  table1 t1 on t1.id=mt.table_id
left join
  table2 t2 on t2.id=mt.table_id
) a
where Year(a.datefld)=2014
```

I have updated the SQL and also did a sqlfiddler for it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b9ce/1

Comment: No, joining is not a solution. master table doesn't have any date values. So `Year(mt.dateColumnName)` is not valid as dateColumnName in master table either contains `dateColumn` or `date_column`. These two columns in table1, table2 contains the actual date.